# How can I convert the content of a list in xml content into a list using .net?Assigning OtsInstallmentsDetails elements in InstallmentList to the list

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-mvc

Here is XML:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"">
    <soap:Body>
        <ControlApplicationsResponse xmlns=\"http://FSM\">
            <ControlApplicationsResult>
                <ErrorMessage xmlns=\"">kaydı var</ErrorMessage>
                <ResponseCode xmlns=\"http://core.intertech.com.tr/\">02</ResponseCode>
                <InstallmentList xmlns=\"">
                    <OtsInstallmentsDetails>
                        <SubscriberNumber>53326</SubscriberNumber>
                        <SubscriberName>ergesrg</SubscriberName>
                        <InvoiceDate>2023-09-22T16:13:00</InvoiceDate>
                        <InvoiceNumber>0001032087</InvoiceNumber>
                        <InstallmentExplanation>1 Taksit</InstallmentExplanation>
                        <InstallmentSeqNumber>1</InstallmentSeqNumber>
                        <PaymentDate>2023-09-25T00:00:00</PaymentDate>
                        <PaymentAmount>1000.00</PaymentAmount>
                        <InstallmentAmount>0.00</InstallmentAmount>
                    </OtsInstallmentsDetails>
```

And my code:

```
string xmlData = result;  // The XML shown above

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlData);

XmlNodeList installmentList = xmlDoc.ChildNodes[1].FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes;

List<OtsInstallment> installments = new List<OtsInstallment>();

foreach (XmlNode installment in installmentList)
{
    if (installment.Name == "OtsInstallmentsDetails")
    {
        OtsInstallment installmentt = new OtsInstallment
        {
            SubscriberNumber = installment["SubscriberNumber"].InnerText,
            SubscriberName = installment["SubscriberName"].InnerText,
            InvoiceDate = DateTime.Parse(installment["InvoiceDate"].InnerText),
            InvoiceNumber = installment["InvoiceNumber"].InnerText,
            InstallmentExplanation = installment["InstallmentExplanation"].InnerText,
            InstallmentSeqNumber = int.Parse(installment["InstallmentSeqNumber"].InnerText),
            PaymentDate = DateTime.Parse(installment["PaymentDate"].InnerText),
            PaymentAmount = decimal.Parse(installment["PaymentAmount"].InnerText),
            InstallmentAmount = decimal.Parse(installment["InstallmentAmount"].InnerText)
        };
        installments.Add(installmentt);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to post your Xml and your classes too if you want to get a help

Comment: There's no reason to read nodes one by one. Use DataContractSerializer or XmlSerializer to deserialize the entire document directly to objects. In fact, if you have the service's WSDL and XSD documents or even their URL, .NET can generate a full SOAP client for the service